# Unable to change site and home url for wordpress domain migration

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

We have migrated word press website to a new domain. We changed home url and site url in wp-options table to new domain via PHPMyAdmin.

Also we have defined new values in wp-config.php file as below:

```
define('WP_HOME', '**New domain**')
define('WP_SITEURL', '**New domain**')
```

But in Database table the old value is updating back.

Is there any tricks to force update back to old domain in database table(wp-options)?